# Thumb pain due to mouse usage

Tags: ergonomics

I am a 25 year old software engineer. I used to play online games where I made nearly 100 clicks per minute. In one such instance I felt a sharp pain in my thumb joint right below my thumbnail, and ever since, I experience this pain in my thumb whenever I click my mouse or use my phones. The pain goes away if I just rest my hand but comes back when I start using my mouse or phone. This has gone on for more than a year and is impacting my career.

Could any of you share workplace adjustments you made that mitigated your ergonomic hand pain? How do you recommend I bring this up in my workplace?

Comment: This is more of a medical question than a Workplace one (the ergonomic one I see we can answer). However, be aware that we are not physicians (perhaps some users here are, but not the point) and you should check with a medic about your pain problem. Seems like the medics you have been consulting are not giving you proper attention. Find better medics... and perhaps it's time to cut down the intensity of your gaming/clicking so you put your health first... that or look for less click-intensive games... anyways this seems something like rest and exercises would alleviate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - This is not really about workplace interactions. Realistically this is a question that needs *medical* advice, not Workplace advice.

Comment: @TheDemonLord if you focus on the ergonomics aspects, yes this is a Workplace thing and can be answered that way. I agree that giving medical advise is not a workplace thing.

Comment: @DarkCygnus - I thought about that - but even accepting the Ergonomics angle, I still think that is a Medical Question. I use a wrist rest myself for my Keyboard, but that was on the advice of my Dr.

Comment: If you're using your right hand for your mouse, your use your left hand for it now. Change the settings on your computer. Then, find other ways to use the mouse less. Memorize shortcuts. Write those shortcuts down next to your computer. And stop playing video games. That's what I had to do myself and in my case, I was able to stop the pain entirely. Your body is your instrument. Take care of it. If you don't, may be you'll need surgical intervention, and even having a surgery doesn't always work. So in other words, you must take drastic actions if you want to remain a software engineer.

Comment: Does your company have an ergonomic consultant? And like Stephan, I also switched my mouse to my nondominant hand, due to ergonomic pain of a different sort.

Comment: Due to some hand and wrist issues, I switched from using a mouse with my right hand to a large (Kensington) tracker ball with my left. Took about 3 days to get fully comfortable with it, but it made a huge difference.

Comment: Did you stop playing game for the whole year ? and it still hurts ? Then, have you thought about going to a different doctor to get a different prescription or treatment ?

Comment: See: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/163639/what-can-i-do-to-mitigate-wrist-other-pains-allowing-me-to-spend-as-much-of-my

Answer (score 6):

[RSI (repetitive strain injury)](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/repetitive-strain-injury-rsi/) is a common issue even before computers were invented, typists were prone to it.

From personal experience the pain goes away if you take up a hobby that excercises your hand in other ways. I had bad pains shooting up my arm until I took up [slinging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)), then they just disappeared.

The pain returned when I was unable to sling for a long time due to my location, and then has disappeared again after I took up [ailao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_knife) which is a war dance involving spinning a weapon while it's on fire. The point is that both of these activities involve my hands using their full range of motion, not that they're the only way.

I would recommend slinging as it's quite low impact and can be done with no prior experience. Ailao is a very dangerous activity (it involves a hooked machete blade and fire) and extremely difficult to even get started on so it's not suitable for casual interest. But any activity that works your hands should do.

I'm not a physiotherapist, this is just what has worked for me and my results were almost immediate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing but is RSI chronic ? I have been having this pain for more than an year

Comment: Yep as far as I know, mine started and just kept getting worse until I could barely do anything on computer. Right now it has totally cleared up. Unlike physio which didn't do much for me except alleviate the pain a little bit slowly. I know from experience that it WILL re-occur if I don't do something about it (and giving up gaming is not an option).

Comment: Yes, RSI is a chronic condition. Yes, physical therapy is the first line of treatment, along with replacing keyboard and pointing device with more ergonomically friendly ones. In serious cases surgery may eventually be required to relieve pressure on the nerve. Occupational hazard, I'm afraid. Your employer may be willing to pay for the ergonomic input devices; your health coverage should pay for treatment. I've been lucky and didn't start having problems until age-related effects (stenosis) started hitting me, but it is far from uncommon, especially in folks who grew up gaming.

Comment: I couldn't help but imagine @Kilisi practicing Ailao while riding a bike as in his Profile Pic... hehehe... anyways, exercising the affected part so it is stronger makes sense, instead of just "using it" for gaming and work (not exercising it).

Comment: @DarkCygnus certainly strengthens the limb, but it also flushes out toxins and has other nice affects. I'm not keen on trying it on the bike though... hehe... I've had enough burns and cuts just doing it properly.

Comment: I also recommend warmth, like wrist bands or gloves, to improve circulation.

Comment: Assembly line workers can also get this. If you sit there and put in the same screw in the same position for 8 hours a day, you're going to get RSI.